# Is it possible to use the Windows icon picker dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog

In my code I would like my user to be able to select an icon from anywhere on their computer. The icon can be a standalone `.ico` or it can be an icon from within an `.exe` or a `.dll` - as in, not only the default displaying icon of the `.exe/dll` but also any other icon contained within it.

In an ideal world I would like to be able to use this native Windows icon picker dialog:

[image: Windows Icon Picker Dialog]

But I don't know how to use it - is it possible?
This dialog would be ideal for me because it appears to only let users browse to either icons or `.exe`s and `.dll`s as standard.

If my users were only able to use standalone `.ico` files then I would take the route of using the `CommonOpenFileDialog` class found in the `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell` nuget package for Windows Visa+ and the `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` for older systems - something like this:

```
private string SelectWinXPIcon()
{
    using (WinForms.OpenFileDialog ofd = new WinForms.OpenFileDialog()
    {
        Filter = "Icon files (*.ico)|*.ico",
    })
    {
        WinForms.DialogResult result = ofd.ShowDialog();
        switch (result)
        {
            case WinForms.DialogResult.OK:
            case WinForms.DialogResult.Yes:
                return ofd.FileName;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}

private string SelectWinVistaIcon()
{
    using (CommonOpenFileDialog dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog
    {
        DefaultDirectory = @"C:\",
        AllowNonFileSystemItems = false,
        EnsurePathExists = true,
        Multiselect = false,
        NavigateToShortcut = true
    })
    {
        dialog.Filters.Add(new CommonFileDialogFilter("Icon Files (*.ico)", ".ico"));
        CommonFileDialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

        switch (result)
        {
            case CommonFileDialogResult.Ok:
                return dialog.FileName;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But this route, as far as I am aware, would not allow my users to select an icon from within a `.exe/dll`?

If there is no way to use the Icon Picker Dialog, is there an alternative method to extracting the icons out of `.exe/dll`s which would also allow for standalone `.ico` files to be selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done via the shell32 PickIconDlg function, which you can easily invoke using the [pinvoke site](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.pickicondlg) for reference. The function will return the filename and an index, you can then extract the icon handle with [the shell32 ExtractIconEx function](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/ExtractIconEx.html). You can then convert the icon handle to a GDI icon or WPF ImageSource.

As an example, declare an image in your XAML to display the icon that the user chooses:

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" Stretch="None" />
```

And then use this code in your window load handler to display the dialog, load it, convert it to an ImageSource and display it:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int PickIconDlg(IntPtr hwndOwner, System.Text.StringBuilder lpstrFile, int nMaxFile, ref int lpdwIconIndex);

[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern uint ExtractIconEx(string szFileName, int nIconIndex, IntPtr[] phiconLarge, IntPtr[] phiconSmall, uint nIcons);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);

private const int MAX_PATH = 0x00000104;

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // show the Pick Icon Dialog
    int index = 0;
    int retval;
    var handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
    var iconfile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + @"\shell32.dll";
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(iconfile, MAX_PATH);
    retval = PickIconDlg(handle, sb, sb.MaxCapacity, ref index);

    if (retval != 0)
    {
        // extract the icon
        var largeIcons = new IntPtr[1];
        var smallIcons = new IntPtr[1];
        ExtractIconEx(sb.ToString(), index, largeIcons, smallIcons, 1);

        // convert icon handle to ImageSource
        this.myImage.Source = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(largeIcons[0],
            Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        // clean up
        DestroyIcon(largeIcons[0]);
        DestroyIcon(smallIcons[0]);
    }
}
```

That will work with DLLs/EXEs etc as well as standalone .ICO files.

Comment: That works fantastically - thank you. Can I ask what the 500 is for?

Comment: Sorry, that's a bit of sloppy coding on my part. It's the number of bytes allocated for the `StringBuilder`, which is passed into `PickIconDlg` as `sb.MaxCapacity` so that the function doesn't trash memory. The `PickIconDlg` documentation states that it should be set to `MAX_PATH`, I've updated the code accordingly.